# Get Drives available on Azure VM from code

Tags: file, azure, virtual-machine

Through code Can I get the list of drives available on Azure VM(Medium size instance) along with their sizes..I am looking for a way where i can store the file temporarily on VM disk and delete it after reading from it.

THanks for you time

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Is it for IaaS (virtual machines) or for PaaS (Web/Worker roles)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Neil Mackenzie's post about local storage: https://convective.wordpress.com/2009/05/09/local-storage-on-windows-azure/.

It's as simple as doing `RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("<name>").RootPath` and then performing your file operations in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Do take a look at this Azure Storage [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-create-storage-account/). They are essentially page blobs which can be mounted on your web/worker role's file system. One catch with Azure drives is that it only allows one instance to write to that while other instances have read only access to it.

HTH.